# Asp.NET download of Excel Spreadsheet from Windows 2012 server causes error

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

We have an ASP.NET (.NET framework 4.0) page used to download an .xlsx file.  This works fine from the webpage running on Windows 2008. However, when we download from the page on a Windows 2012 Server (IIS 8.5), we get this error: "Excel found unreadable content in suchandsuch.xlxs. Do you want to recover the contents of the workbook?" If you do recover it, it says the workbook has been repaired, and we can open it.  However, the end-user will not appreciate this.
We have confirmed the error occurs on 2 different Windows 2012 servers, and does not occur on 2 Windows 2008 servers.

We have tried, based on some posts, to modify the Response.ContentType, first trying "application/vnd.ms-excel", and then "application/application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet".

But the error persists.

Comment: If you download the file, but don't open it with excel. Instead, save it and then open it with Notepad. Look at the end of the file, is it well-formed XML or is the XML cut-off, or with extra characters?  Could you show the first 100 char and last 100 char?

Comment: The start of the xml portion is this:

Comment: The beginning of the html portion is this: <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><title>
 Visa (Excel) Bulk Query
</title><link href="../../Stylesheets/webCLASS.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" /></head>
<body class="Default">
    <form name="aspnetForm" method="post" action="/webclass/visa/bulkQuery/ExcelBulkQuery.aspx" id="aspnetForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div>
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTTARGET" id="__EVENTTARGET" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTARGUMENT" id="__EVENTARGUMENT" value="" />

Comment: And the end of the file has this:
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
Sys.Application.add_init(function() {
    $create(Sys.UI._Timer, {"enabled":true,"interval":15000,"uniqueID":"ctl00$PageContentPlaceHolder$autorefreshTimer"}, null, null, $get("ctl00_PageContentPlaceHolder_autorefreshTimer"));
});
//]]>
</script>
</form>
</body>
</html>

Comment: The comment by tgolisch and then posting of the start and end of the html made me realize that the spreadsheet, when downloaded from Windows 2012, contains the ASP.NET page markup (markup of the page used for the download)  after the Excel content. When downloaded from Windows 2008, only the Excel content is present.

Comment: Do you want to post the answer, or close it, or should I post the answer? (so other S/O users will benefit from the solution)

Comment: Tfolisch's observation was useful. However, there is no solution yet. The download from ASP.NET from a Windows 2012 server running IIS 8.5 results in a corrupted xlsx file containing the aspx markup of the page used for the download. We have tried various changes to the Response.ContentType and none have worked.

Comment: Do you have the source code to the app which is generating the Excel file?  The little bit of output that you've shown looks like it contains some AJAX. I've seen servers strip-out or disable ajax or inline scripts sometimes.

Comment: Rather than struggle with this any longer, we found an alternate solution, which is to email the zipped spreadsheet to the user requesting the download.